# Fedora 21 - Problem waking up after suspend

Tags: fedora, suspend

I recently installed a Fedora 21 64-bit workstation. In the *Power* tab of **GNOME Tweak Tool**, I set the option *Power Button Action* to *Suspend* -
[image]

The power indicator LED on my laptop usually starts blinking when the system is suspended. But after I open the lid, the power indicator LED remains on but there does not seem to be any other action taking place. The screen remains blank. Even pressing the power key does not help. Ultimately I have to long press the power key and turn off the laptop. Any suggestion as to what might be causing it?

Comment: You'd better ask this question in #fedora (at freenode). ;-)

Comment: Or if your not lucky and get an answer here you can try: ask.fedoraproject.org, I use it and most my questions have been answered.

Comment: I already tried asking it at #fedora and Fedora Forums. Will try at Ask Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Some Computers these days will not come out of suspend unless you hit the bottom left most key on the keyboard. Sometimes it maybe the fn key or shift key.